# c++ shared_ptr Assertion `px != 0' failed

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, point-cloud-library

I want to use thread in order to process the point clouds parallelly.
Firstly, I initialized a output vector (projected_clouds) before calling the fillColoredCloud() function. Inside the function, I assign the point clouds as a instance of a vector. When I try to call this vector outside of the function for example:

```
cout << projected_clouds[0]->points.size();
```

I get "Assertion `px != 0' failed." and my codes:

```
auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::mutex mutex_;
int num_threads = 12;
std::vector<boost::thread> thread_vec(num_threads);

std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr> projected_clouds(num_threads);

for(int i=0; i<num_threads; i++)
{
    const unsigned int  start_index = cloud_in->size()/num_threads*i;
    const unsigned int  end_index = cloud_in->size()/num_threads*(i+1);

    Cloud::Ptr partial_cloud(new Cloud);

    if(i==num_threads-1)
    {
        partial_cloud->points.assign(cloud_in->points.begin()+start_index, cloud_in->points.end());
    }else{
        partial_cloud->points.assign(cloud_in->points.begin()+start_index, cloud_in->points.begin()+end_index);
    }
    thread_vec[i] = boost::thread(boost::bind(&CameraProjection::fillColoredCloud, this, partial_cloud, mat_point_transformer,
                                                      img_size ,reshaped_img, &mutex_, projected_clouds, i));
}

for (auto & iterator : thread_vec) {
    iterator.join();
}
cout << projected_clouds[0]->points.size();
```

fillColoredCloud():

```
void CameraProjection::fillColoredCloud(Cloud::Ptr cloud_in,Eigen::Matrix4d mat_point_transformer,cv::Size img_size,cv::Mat cv_img, std::mutex* mutex_,
                                        std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr>& projected_clouds, int i)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr projected_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

    for (const auto &point : cloud_in->points)
    {
        auto pair = CameraProjection::pointInImagePlane(point, mat_point_transformer, img_size);
        bool in = pair.first;
        cv::Point point_in_image = pair.second;

        if(in)
        {
            pcl::PointXYZRGB colored_point = CameraProjection::giveColoredPoint(cv_img, point_in_image, point);
            projected_cloud->points.push_back(colored_point);
        }
    }
    projected_clouds[i] = projected_cloud;
    std::cout << "fillColoredCloud() running" << std::endl;
}
```

Error is:

```
 /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

Comment: I do not see such assertion anywhere in your code. Please post a [mcve] . Throwing around `new` casually in those function calls is a huge red flag for me. Especially given that `boost:thread` copies the arguments.

Comment: I added the error.

Answer (score 3):

`boost::bind` should work like [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind): It makes copies of its arguments. That means that your threads are actually working with a copy of `projected_clouds` stored in the object returned by `boost::bind(...)`, and the original vector is untouched (it's all default constructed objects, which if they are `shared_ptr`s will be not point to anything).

Use [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)(/[`boost::ref`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/ref.html)) to prevent making copies (or use a pointer like you did with the mutex)

Seeing that you are using C++11, it's easier to just use a lambda:

```cpp
thread_vec[i] = boost::thread([=, &mutex_, &projected_clouds] {
    fillColoredCloud(partial_cloud, mat_point_transformer, img_size, reshaped_img, &mutex_, projected_clouds, i);
});
```